# Android studio доступ к html тегам

Tags: javascript, java, html, android-studio

Я в Android studio создаю приложение средствами HTML, Css, JS(дабы владею ими). Вопрос: как я могу получить доступ к HTML тегу(например "p"), в который динамически вставляю текст(строку) через JS и дальше манипулировать с этим текстов. Суть задачи: отправить этот текст по Viber пользователю. Может возможно его получить из JS функции, которая возвращает этот текст?

Comment: Посмотрите в сторону JSOUP....

Comment: Спс, буду юзать))